# How to convert .hdf5 to .h5 keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a pre-trained hdf5 model background removal model that I've used from [here](https://github.com/aadityavikram/Background-Removal). I'm looking to convert it to h5 as `coremltools` converter requires that type.

So far, the coremltools python script gives the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Expected model format: [SavedModel | [concrete_function] | tf.keras.Model | .h5], got main_model.hdf5
```

Comment: Its the same formal, just rename the file to .h5

Comment: Thank you! You can add this as an answer if you want!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's literally the same format, so you can change the extension by renaming the file to `.h5` and it should work fine.

Comment: So, what is the purpose of creating two extensions for the same file format? I think there should be any minor difference.